# Mount folder file handling using Camel 2.10 on LINUX

Tags: java, osgi, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I am using Camel 2.10 version inwhich we are facing this issue.
The JBoss Fuse 6.0 is running on the RHEL and we have mounted a Windows shared folder on the server linux folder is `/mnt/sharedwin`.

Now we are processing file from this folder using file component as below.

The from endpoint is as below

`file:/mnt/sharedwin/Current?preMove=/opt/jboss/fuse/data/target/processing&move=archive/$simple{date:now:yyyyMMdd}/$simple{file:name}&moveFailed=errorFile/$simple{date:now:yyyyMMdd}/$simple{file:name}`

When running the application we are getting following WARN msg and file are not getting moved to archive folder.

**Caused by: java.io.IOException: Renaming file from: /mnt/sharedwin/Current/XYZ.csv to: /opt/jboss/fuse/data/target/processing/XYZ.csv failed due cannot delete from file: /mnt/sharedwin/Current/XYZ.csv after copy succeeded**

Am I missing some parameters in file URL, please help.

Comment: Maybe its permission errors, that the user is not allowed to delete the files on the unix mount.

Comment: Agree with Claus here. I have mounted a windows share on a Centos box and can delte file etc from the windows share via Camel. Make sure you mount the file with a user id(windows ID) that can read and write to the share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Claus and Namphibian it was actually the issue with write access to the service account used to map the windows folder as suggested by by both of you. 
It's now working once we provided the access. 
Thanks Again.